# jQuery Trent Richardson's DateTimePicker: Set picker to value in textbox using class selector

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

I have a couple textboxes in a templatefield of an ASP.NET gridview that I want to use a [datetime picker](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/) (both date and time portions.) Due to the way ASP.NET generates the front end ID of controls, the easiest way to select the textboxes is by class. Getting the textboxes to do the datetime picker wasn't hard:

The problem is, every time the datetimepicker opens up, it clears the prepopulated value from the textbox and the datetimepicker doesn't default to the datetime present in the textbox. If there was a single textbox and/or I had the ClientID beforehand, I could set the defaultValue relatively easily. But the actual HTML ClientID of the textboxes don't end with the asp id so I can't use an endswith function (`ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1_tbStartDate_0`) and I can't use `<%# tbStartDate.ClientID %>` since the textboxes are only generated after the Update button is pushed. But I am not sure how to go about it with the jQuery class selector.

I have ASP.NET formatting the datetime to the default format that the datetimepicker uses for convenience sake.

Simplified page below:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
   <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.9.1.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <link rel="stylesheet" media="all" type="text/css" href="Styles/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" media="all" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
</Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">

   jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        $(".dateTimePickerClass").datetimepicker();
    });

   <asp:GridView ID="gridview1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SQLDataSource1">
      <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
      <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Start Date" SortExpression="startDate">
         <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("startDate") %>'></asp:Label>
         </ItemTemplate>
         <EditItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox CssClass="dateTimePickerClass" ID="tbStartDate" runat="server"
                 Text='<%# Bind("startDate", "{0:MM/dd/yyyy H:mm}") %>'></asp:TextBox>
         </EditItemTemplate>
      </asp:TemplateField>
      <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="End Date" SortExpression="endDate">
         <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("endDate") %>'></asp:Label>
         </ItemTemplate>
         <EditItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox CssClass="dateTimePickerClass" ID="endDate" runat="server"
                 Text='<%# Bind("endDate", "{0:MM/dd/yyyy H:mm}") %>'></asp:TextBox>
         </EditItemTemplate>
      </asp:TemplateField>
   </GridView>
   <asp:SQLDataSource id="SQLDataSource1" runat="server" />
</Content>
```

And the html generated:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Example</title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.9.1.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="all" type="text/css" href="Styles/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="all" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function () {
            $(".dateTimePickerClass").datetimepicker({ onClose: function (value) {$('input.datetime').val(value);}});
            });
    </script>

    <div>
        <table cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_gvHolds" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">&nbsp;</th><th scope="col">Start Date</th><th scope="col">End Date</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Update &nbsp;Cancel</td>
                <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$gvHolds$ctl02$tbStartDate" type="text" 
                    value="01/04/2013 10:43" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_gvHolds_tbStartDate_0" class="dateTimePickerClass" />
                </td>
                <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$gvHolds$ctl02$tbEndDate" type="text" 
                    id="ContentPlaceHolder1_gvHolds_tbEndDate_0" class="dateTimePickerClass" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try grabbing the HTML generated by your ASP and seeing if something there is interfering with these things.  That would be a good debugging approach.  If you're still stuck, you might post that HTML (as simplified as possible, of course) in your question.

Comment: Added the simplified HTML.

Comment: Playing around with the simplified HTML and a working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LmUnr/), I could not get it to work until I noticed I was running jquery-ui-1.9.1.js and the jsfiddle uses jquery-ui-1.8.16.js. Switching to the old version works.

Comment: I am still somewhat new to JQuery. I didn't know if it was a bug in how I was calling datetimepicker or even if the picker was suppose to default to the value in the textbox since it doesn't explicitly say that as far as I can tell.

Comment: This http://jsfiddle.net/b5KMg/1/ fiddle shows that you can have an initial date in the text box and opening the datepicker won't make it go away.  I'm not sure why it is going away in your case.

Answer (score -1):

Playing around with the simplified HTML and a working JSFiddle, I could not get it to work until I noticed I was running jquery-ui-1.9.1.js and the jsfiddle uses jquery-ui-1.8.16.js. Switching to the old version works.